# stage doesn't display world maps

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone
I'm trying to run some world maps in stage simulator.
Everything works when writing

```
rosrun roscd stageros willow-erratic.world
```

while, when using any other world file (already present in default folder or added to it from internet), I get errors like the following one:

```
    OpenGL Warning: No pincher, please call crStateSetCurrentPointers() in your SPU
 [Loading willow-four-erratics.world][Image "willow-full.pgm"]
err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
err: Unknown model type laser in world file. (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
```

Another error I encountered is

```
ubisum@ubisum:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/world$ rosrun stage stageros autolab.world
OpenGL Warning: No pincher, please call crStateSetCurrentPointers() in your SPU
 [Loading autolab.world][Include chatterbox.inc][Include irobot.inc][Include hokuyo.inc][Include map.inc][Image "bitmaps/autolab.png"]
[FATAL] [1360681774.773654192]: number of position models and laser models must be equal in the world file.
[FATAL] [1360681774.777624430]: BREAKPOINT HIT
    file = /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/src/stageros.cpp
    line=208

Rilevato trace/breakpoint (core dump creato)
```

Do you know which are the causes of these two errors and how to solve them?

thanks for support

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55022/stage-doesn%27t-display-world-maps/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like you're using old world files. As of Fuerte (Stage 4.1.1) lasers have been replaced by rangers in the new world file formats as described [here](http://blog.aus10.org/?p=125). There are also other questions like this here on [answers.ros](http://answers.ros.org/question/38265).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0